# Форматирование строк в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Как превратить это:

```
: kamazz : kori: kamazz : kori: hoho : 123
```

В это:

```
kamazz:kori
kamazz:kori
hoho:123
```

Пожалуйста помогите, нужна ваша помощь :)

Comment: количество пробелов между строками может быть разным? Между словами всегда стоит двоеточие?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно как то, так

```py
a = ": kamazz : kori: kamazz : kori: hoho : 123"
lst = a.split(":")
keys = [i.strip() for i in lst[0::2] if i != ""]
values = [i.strip() for i in lst[1::2] if i != ""]

result = []
for i in range(len(keys)):
    result.append(f"{values[i]}:{keys[i]}")

print("\n".join(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Прежде всего мы избавляемся от всех пробелов и разделяем все слова через [`split()`](https://pythonz.net/references/named/str.split/), чтобы получить список:

```py
l = ': kamazz : kori: kamazz : kori: hoho : 123'.replace(' ', '').split(":")
# ['', 'kamazz', 'kori', 'kamazz', 'kori', 'hoho', '123']
```

После этого мы будем доставать все элементы в парах, начиная со второго, при помощи [f-строк](https://shultais.education/blog/python-f-strings) и [join()](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/python-join) — разделителем будет `\n`, т.к., насколько я понял, после каждой пару надо переходить на новую строку:

```py
print('\n'.join([f'{l[i]}:{l[i+1]}' for i in range(1, len(l), 2)]))
```

Если нужен вариант менее заковыристый, то можно сделать это через цикл:

```py
res = ''
for i in range(1, len(l), 2):
  res += l[i] + ':' + l[i+1] + '\n'
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
s1 = ': kamazz : kori: kamazz : kori: hoho : 123'
items = list(filter(bool, re.split(r'\s*?:\s*', s1)))
print('\n'.join(f'{i1}:{i2}' for i1, i2 in zip(items[::2], items[1::2])))
```

```latex
kamazz:kori
kamazz:kori
hoho:123
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю обработать строку с помощью регулярных выражений, чтобы вытащить пары. Дальше их можно объединить через join().

```
import re

txt = ': kamazz : kori: kamazz : kori: hoho : 123'
pairs = [':'.join(e) for e in re.findall('(\w+)\s+:\s+(\w+)', txt)]
print(*pairs, sep='\n')
```

Вывод:

```
kamazz:kori
kamazz:kori
hoho:123
```